# How to restrict the domain of output in tikz (to save computation and just see what is interesting)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\newcommand{\newvar}{\pgfmathsetmacro}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]%, transparency group, blend mode = multiply]
    \newvar{\num}{10}
    \newvar{\val}{\num-1}
    \newvar{\scale}{1}

    \tikzset{
        square/.pic={
        \draw[line width=1mm, pic actions]  (0, 0) -- (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;
    }
    }
    \tikzset{
        scaledc/.pic={
        \foreach \i in {(0, 0), (\scale, 0), (0, \scale), (0, 2*\scale), (\scale, 2*\scale)}{
        \draw[line width=1mm] \i pic[fill=blue] {square};
        }
    }
    }

    \tikzset{
    scaledd/.pic={
        \foreach \i in {(0, 0), (-1*\scale, 0), (0, -1*\scale), (0, -2*\scale), (-1*\scale, -2*\scale)}{
        \draw[line width=1mm] \i pic[fill=red] {square};
        }
    }
    }


    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
    \begin{scope}[blend mode = multiply]
        \foreach \i in {0,...,\num}{
        \foreach \j in {0,...,\val}{
            \path (3*\j+\i, -\j+3*\i) pic {scaledc};
            \path (3*\j+\i+2, -\j+3*\i+1) pic {scaledd};
        }
        }
    \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above code gives a tessellation of the plane by a c-shaped tile and its mirror image. When the `\scale` is set to 1 and `\num` is set to 10, the output is the following (beautiful):
[image: Tessellation]

However, I want to set the `\scale` very high, namely 53, and `\num` also very high (at least 40).

Tikz seems to not care if the `\scale` is higher than 35. The output does not change on increasing the `\scale` further.

I am only interested in a small region (10 x 10) around the origin.

Can I somehow tell tikz to forget about doing anything outside this region so that it can generate a richer output?

EDIT:

Let me explain my point by taking an example. Fix `scale=11`. Then the cshaped tile becomes

[image: scaled c shape]

Now set `\num=10`. Then rendered tessellation is
[image: num is 10]

A lot of squares near the center of the image (the origin) are not covered. To study the behaviour of the tessellation better, we need to increase the value of `\num` to get a better picture. Here is what we see with `\num=20`.

[image: num is 20]

This all works fine. But if I increase the value of `\num` to 40, tikz does not generate any new data, and it also takes a long time to execute the code. My interest is only in a small window around the origin.

Comment: Hey! You might want to use clipping! You just have to insert `\clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);` before drawing anything!

Comment: Thanks for the help. The clipping command does restrict the output to the desired domain. But tikz is not able to realize that it is wasting time on parts which are outside the domain. As a result, setting `\num` very high leads to a very long waiting time and with no extra detail (perhaps because it gives up after a large enough value of `\num`).

Comment: There are some things I do not understand. `\scale` controls how far the the squares are apart from each other. Why would you want to increase it? And if you only want to draw a small subset of the thing, shouldn't you just restrict the loop? Also `tile1` is not used here. (I can see how this may make sense but would like to ask you to explain better what you intend to do.)

Comment: I want to to be able to change the `\scale` to see the behaviour of the tessellation under various scalings of the two tiles (one a cshape and the other its mirror image). The thing is that `2 x cshape` is quite different from `cshape` (for instance, it is not even connected). If I restrict the loop, then all I see is a rarified collection of unit squares. Increasing the number of iterations makes the thing denser. Also, `\tile1` has crept in from my previous codes. Let me edit the question to make my point clearer. Thanks.

Comment: First things first, your rendered tessellation is way too cool!! For your problem, the only way I see would be to only draw the squares that fall in the centered area (you'll have to the test it by hand, sooo without pic?) BUT I don't know about the computation time it will require, I have no idea how tikz do the clipping (so tikz might do exactly this but in a way optimized way) and this might be a really wrong way to do it (as I'm kind of a big noob when it comes to use specific and already implemented things in tikz) so it might be a good thing to wait for other replies or comments ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the solution I was talking about in my comment :
The idea is to do the clipping by hand, so for each square, we test if it's in the main area. It might not be the best way to do it. It might actually be a (really) bad one, but because I wrote it, well... it costs nothing to post it! (If somebody think it's a bad answer, tell me and I would remove it!)

To encode the 4 tests ( -L < X < L and -L < Y < L ), I used the sum of the four signs of differences : L-X, X-(-L), L-Y and Y-(-L). I don't know if there is a better and more optimized way to do four calculation and four tests, but it works like that and kind of easy to write!
(note: sign(X) equals -1, 0 or 1, so the sum is suppose to be 4 is all inequalities are true)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\newcommand{\newvar}{\pgfmathsetmacro}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]%, transparency group, blend mode = multiply]
    \newvar{\num}{50}
    \newvar{\val}{\num-1}
    \newvar{\scale}{11}

    \newvar{\alimit}{10}

    \newcommand{\drawsquare}[3]{
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\dum{sign(\alimit-(#1))+sign(#1+\alimit)+sign(\alimit-(#2))+sign(#2+\alimit)}
      \ifnum\dum=4
      \draw[fill=#3] (#1-.5,#2-.5) rectangle ++ (1,1);
      \fi
    }

    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
      \begin{scope}[blend mode = multiply]

        \foreach \i in {0,...,\num}{
          \message{\i,}
          \foreach \j in {0,...,\val}{

            \foreach \x/\y in {0/0, \scale/0, 0/\scale, 0/2*\scale, \scale/2*\scale}{
              \drawsquare{3*\j+\i+\x}{-\j+3*\i+\y}{red}
            }

            \foreach \x/\y in {0/0, -\scale/0, 0/-\scale, 0/-2*\scale, -\scale/-2*\scale}{
              \drawsquare{3*\j+\i+2+\x}{-\j+3*\i+1+\y}{blue}
            }

          }
        }

      \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The computation time hugely depends on the `\limit` value, but for small values, for example `limit=10` and `num=50`, it's less than 30s on my computer. (I left the `\message{\i,}` I used to evaluate this time.)

Comment: Thanks for appreciating my tessellation. I think your code does a much better job than mine. It is also displaying numbers which tell me how much time will it take to finally produce the output. And I think the output is also richer.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, if you need to draw it with high values of `\num` and `\limit`, it might be way much easier to do it with faster programming language. I had a figure that was taking something like 2 minutes with tikz and I wanted to increase the size even more so I rewrite it in C++ (with the Cairo library) and it took less than a second to compute! So, in the case of figure with a huge number of part, you might want to take a look at other things than tikz (not specially c++/cairo) and it might be easy as you only have colored squares to draw! :)

Comment: I see. I think I cold give python a try.